# Amalgamate unique methods from multiple classes on interface?

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes that contain unique DB repositories. Both interact with different DBs. I would like to amalgamate these repositories onto a single interface. Is this possible or will it always be the case that neither class will be deemed to fully implement all of the interface members?

I would like something like this,

```
public class FooDatabase : IFooBarDatabases
{
    public IFooRepository FooRepository { get; set; }
}

public class BarDatabase : IFooBarDatabases
{
    public IBarRepository BarRepository { get; set; }
}

public interface IFooBarDatabases
{
    IFooRepository FooRepository { get; }

    IBarRepository BarRepository { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Repositories should be "database independant"

*A Repository mediates between the domain and data mapping layers, acting like an in-memory domain object collection. Client objects construct query specifications declaratively and submit them to Repository for satisfaction. Objects can be added to and removed from the Repository, as they can from a simple collection of objects, and the mapping code encapsulated by the Repository will carry out the appropriate operations behind the scenes*

Now the way how you will create yuor repository really depends by your domain rather then what database will be hit: a repository should not care about what database will be hit

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

Comment: Yes, but I can't get away from the fact that I have different data in different databases. I don't want my consumer to have to specify which database to go to e.g. passing down the connection string. I wish to have one apparent data source for the consumer.